# Django: Storing relative and absolute image paths in ImageField

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

On my site users can upload their own profile pictures, which I manage through an ImageField in a UserProfile model that extends the core User model. Here's a simplified version of the UserProfile model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='img', blank=True, null=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='img', default='img/profile/default_profile.png', blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
```

I'm using PIL to create a thumbnail version of the uploaded image.

To display the profile picture in my template, I'm using the `url` function recommended in the docs as follows:

```
{{ user.get_profile.profile_picture.url }}
```

The problem I'm dealing with is when a user connects their account to Facebook, and wants to use their Facebook profile picture as their profile picture on my site.

What is the best way to handle displaying either an image the user uploaded, or their Facebook profile picture, depending on the setting the user has specified?

If I store the path to the Facebook profile picture in the `profile_picture` field, I'd be forced to do a check before displaying each profile picture on the site, otherwise I'd get my MEDIA_ROOT/MEDIA_URL pre-prended to the image:

```
/media/https://graph.facebook.com/[fbid]/picture
```

My other option is to add the MEDIA_ROOT/MEDIA_URL to the `profile_picture` field whenever an image is uploaded. Unfortunately the only way to do this is in the `add_profile_picture` function in my views.py, both because Django defaults to storing paths to images without a beginning forward slash, and because PIL gets fiesty if you try to open an image whose relative path begins with a forward slash. However if I do pre-pend the full image path I don't have to use the `url` function in my templates, and I can just display the image as follows and it will work correctly whether it's an uploaded image or a Facebook image:

```
{{ user.get_profile.profile_picture }}
```

However both of these options feel like hacks, and I feel like there must be a more efficient way to do this, so I'm turning to SO for some inspiration/guidance on best practices here.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of possibilities:

1. on write, override `save()` and massage the given value into the desired value before writing to the database, or
2. on read, create a method which inspects the stored value and massages it into the appropriate pattern. Apply the `@property` decorator so you can access it directly from the template

I might add that in my own battle along these lines (same but different), I abandoned the ImageField altogether in favour of a CharField and let the routines above handle the unique imaging minutiae (eg: thumbnailing).

Comment: +1 thanks, ended up going with something similar to option 1.